# Pulling MS Word Content Control from another Word Doc Content Contol

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a bit of code here that opens up two word documents, and I am trying to transfer the contents of one Content Control (Rich Text) to another Documents Rich Text Content Control. Everything transfers over properly, but for some reason, after it copies itself over, it just keeps pasting new blank lines and never moves to the next CC in the For Each loop. Any ideas how I can force it to the next Content Control after the paste? I've tried PasteandFormat and it has the same issue.

```
    Sub PreClear()
    
    Dim wrd As Word.Application
    Dim wrdm As Word.Application
    Dim pc As Word.Document
    Dim pcm As Word.Document
    Dim CC As ContentControl
    Dim CCTag As String
    
    Set wrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrd.DisplayAlerts = 0
    wrd.Visible = True
    Set pc = wrd.Documents.Open("DestinationFilePath", ReadOnly:=True)
    
    Set wrdm = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdm.DisplayAlerts = 0
    wrdm.Visible = False
    Set pcm = wrdm.Documents.Open("SourceFilePath", ReadOnly:=True)
    
    
    For Each CC In pc.ContentControls
       
        CCTag = CC.Tag
    
             
        If CCTag <> "" And Left(CCTag, 4) = "PCM_" Then
                If CC.Type = wdContentControlRichText Or CC.Type = wdContentControlText Then
                    pcm.SelectContentControlsByTag(CCTag).Item(1).Copy
                    CC.Range.Paste
                End If
        End If
    
    Next CC
      
    
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code you have posted I can't see any reason why the code is getting stuck, but there is no need to use the clipboard. Instead you can simply assign the text, or the formatted text, of one range to another, as follows:

```
  If Left(CC.Tag, 4) = "PCM_" Then
    If CC.Type = wdContentControlRichText Then
      CC.Range.FormattedText = pcm.SelectContentControlsByTag(CC.Tag).item(1).Range.FormattedText
    ElseIf CC.Type = wdContentControlText Then
      CC.Range.Text = pcm.SelectContentControlsByTag(CC.Tag).item(1).Range.Text
    End If
  End If
```

Comment: Thank you @Timothy but when I run this I get a 'No such interface supported' error. I have the MS Word 16 Library checked off as well. Any ideas?

Comment: CC.Range.FormattedText = pcm.SelectContentControlsByTag(CC.Tag).Item(1).Range.FormattedText

Comment: @MattHenry I am not getting any errors at all with that code even if the source control is a plain text rather than rich text control. I am using O365.